# Classes dentro de classes (Python/Django)

Tags: python, django

Ola, 
Estou começando a estudar sobre python por conta do Django. Estou com uma duvida que muitos podem considerar trivial mas que não sei a resposta.

Estou construindo um Modelo com as seguintes características:

```
class Candidato(models.Model):
   nome        =   models.CharField(max_length=300, required=True)
   mail        =   models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)
   fone        =   models.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)
   nascimento  =   models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
   cpf         =   models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   rg          =   models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   trabalho    =   models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)
   mae         =   ???????????
   pai         =   ???????????
```

E preciso que os campos "mae" e "pai" sejam dois objetos com a seguinte estrutura:

```
class Mae(models.Model):
   nome        =   models.CharField(max_length=300, required=True)
   nascimento  =   models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, required=True)
   cpf         =   models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   rg          =   models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   mail       =   models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)
   fone        =   models.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)
   trabalho    =   models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)

class Pai(models.Model):
   nome        =   models.CharField(max_length=300, required=True)
   nascimento  =   models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False, required=True)
   cpf         =   models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   rg          =   models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
   email       =   models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)
   fone        =   models.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)
   trabalho    =   models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)
   membro      =   models.BooleanField()
```

Como faço para referências um objeto "Pai" e um "Mae" dentro do objeto "Candidato"?

Agradeço desde já a ajuda de quem puder me auxiliar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está procurando uma relação [Many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/), veja:

```
class Mae(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Pai(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Candidato(models.Model):
    mae = models.ForeignKey(Mae, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pai = models.ForeignKey(Pai, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Veja mais sobre os diferentes tipos de campos nos modelos [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/)

Comment: Vou ler sobre esse tipo de relação. Muito obrigado pela ajuda :D

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overlfow! :) Se a resposta solucionou o seu problema, não se esqueça de marcar como aceita.

Answer (score 0):

Percebar que as entidades: pai, mãe e candidato tem vários atributos em comum.
Para diminuição de código pode-se usar os modelos abstratos do django.

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
  nome = models.CharField(max_length=300, required=True)
  nascimento = models.DateTimeField(blank=False,null=False,required=True)
  cpf = models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
  rg = models.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
  mail = models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)
  fone =  models.CharField(max_length=20, required=True)
  trabalho = models.EmailField(max_length=300, required=True)

  class Meta:
     abstract = True

 class Pai(Pessoa):
     # algum Atributo para Pai

 class Mae(Pessoa):
     # algum atributo para Mãe

 class Candidato(Pessoa):
     mae = models.ForeignKey(Mae, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     pai = models.ForeignKey(Pai, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Assim o django não criará a tabela Pessoa e você escrveu menos código e se algum atributo precisar mudar de nome bastará alterar em um único lugar

- Não estou levamdo emconta padrões e boas práticas de modelagem de dados.